# Running Java in VS Code on Windows 10 Education Edition

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run VS Code with Java on a Windows 10 Education laptop.  I did the following to set it up:

1. Downloaded VS Code zip file and extracted and ran it
2. Ran VS Code and installed Microsoft's Java Extensions Pack into it.
3. Downloaded the AdoptOpenJDK zip file for x64 windows and unziped it.
4. In VS Code set the java.home setting to where I had the JDK.
5. Ran a simple java program.
6. Windows Defender pops up saying it blocked network access.  I allow access in the popup.

The VS Code terminal shows the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\22ASF>  & 'c:\Users\22ASF\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.29.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Java\jdk-11.0.9.1\bin\java.exe' '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:62044' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users\22ASF\AppData\Local\Temp\vscodesws_ac98e\jdt_ws\jdt.ls-java-project\bin' 'SimpleLoops' 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

        at SimpleLoops.main(SimpleScanner.java:4)
```

(No text for the actual compilation problem)

When I follow these exact steps on a Windows 7 Professional PC, it works just fine. (Except there is no windows defender window pops.)

**Is there a way I can get this working on a Windows 10 Education Edition laptop?**

Comment: Does it help if you trigger the command `Clean Java Language server workspace cache`? You can see it by `F1` and type the command name in the input box.

Comment: @ShengChen - Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried it out.  When I ran that command, it restarted VS Code, but once it got back up again, I still got the same error.

Comment: @ShengChen - The run option on the `Main` method of the class was giving that error.  But when I used the run "play triangle" in the top right corner of the screen it worked!  Very happy to have a real IDE instead of having to use a website!

Comment: Glad to see the problem resolved. If you don't mind, feel free to create an issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues. I'm actually interested why the code lens shortcut is not working